# Createwindowex invalid handle error

Tags: java, winapi, magnification-api

I am using jna functions to call winapi

```
public muFunction(){
  Magnification.INSTANCE.MagInitialize();
  RECT desktopRect= new RECT();
  HWND desktop = User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow();
  User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(desktop, desktopRect);
  HINSTANCE hInstance =Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

  HWND lsm = User32Extra.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, "MyWindow");
  HWND hwndMag = User32Extra.INSTANCE.CreateWindowEx(new DWORD(0x00000000L), "Magnifier", "MagnifierWindow", new DWORD(0x40000000L|0x0001L|0x10000000L), desktopRect.left, desktopRect.top, desktopRect.right-desktopRect.left, desktopRect.bottom-desktopRect.top, desktop, null, hInstance, null);
  System.out.println(Native.getLastError()); // return 6 as error
}
```

Magnification Api code

```
public interface Magnification extends StdCallLibrary {

    Magnification INSTANCE = (Magnification) Native.loadLibrary("magnification", Magnification.class,
                                                W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    public Boolean MagInitialize();

    public boolean MagSetWindowFilterList(HWND hwndMag, DWORD dword, int i,
            HWND[] excludeHWNDs);

    public boolean MagSetWindowSource(HWND hwndMag, RECT sourceRect);

}
```

I am getting `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error. What is wrong with my code.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the entire error message?!

Comment: System.out.println(Native.getLastError()); prints `6` as code.

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking. This is a mistake that we see almost every time we get a question on Win32. Please read the docs for each function you call. Note carefully the text regarding return values. You ignore this for all api calls. It's a mistake to make the desktop window be the owner. Don't do that. Where is the window class defined?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what happens if we make desktop as owner. There is no issue with class name.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx

Comment: It's unclear if the CreateWindow is actually failing, since you don't check the return code. It's a mistake to call GetLastError unless something has actually failed.

Comment: `CreateWindowEx` function is not failing, it is giving HWND. if it fails it will return HWND as null.

Comment: If it's not failing then why are you checking the error code?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I don't know why it is returning both HWND and error code.

Comment: It's not returning an error code if it succeeds, that's the point.

Comment: @JonathanPotter what is the reason for that function to fail?

Comment: The only failure is yours for calling it when there hasn't been an error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I use 'null' instead of `desktop`, it is giving `Cannot create a top-level child window.` error

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with your code. You don't perform error checking, as has been exhaustively covered in the comments. You really need to sort that out.

You also use magic constants for window style. Please declare named constants so that future readers (i.e. you) can make sense of the code. The key one is your use of `WS_CHILD`. You can't make the desktop window be the parent of your child window. You'll need to provide another window to be the parent.